# Which is the best way to get out of my current questions ban

Tags: discussion

I got on temporary (1 day, if I understand correctly) questions ban. I guess this is due to this question mainly

[Are there multiple Bitcoin markets?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/93841/are-there-multiple-bitcoin-markets)

since it's the only one with a negative vote balance. I'd like to continue asking questions about them, but this site doesn't take it too well to questions about Bitcoins. So I'm trying to see if I can ask questions which are better received, or if I'll have to ask my questions somewhere else.

1. Concerning specifically question [Are there multiple Bitcoin markets?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/93841/are-there-multiple-bitcoin-markets) would it help if I deleted it? I'm not convinced that modifying it will attract upvotes (sometimes people downvote just because one changed the accepted answer), but if modifying is better than deleting, how could I modify it in order to improve it? I need suggestions which are specific to this question, not generic ones such as "make it fit better the Q&A paradigm of the StackExchange network".
2. I would like to ask another question on Bitcoins, i.e.

---

"What's the difference between a Bitcoin Wallet and a Bitcoin
Exchange"

I want to invest a small amount of money in Bitcoin. Reading [this](https://www.investopedia.com/tech/how-to-buy-bitcoin/), I discovered that one should create a Bitcoin Wallet before buying Bitcoins on a Bitcoin Exchange such as Coinbase or Kraken. I don't understand why I should do that, isn't enough to download the Coinbase app, for example? Also, the link says that

> While exchanges offer wallet capabilities to users, it’s not their
>   primary business. Since wallets need to be kept safe and secure,
>   exchanges do not encourage storing of Bitcoins for higher amounts or
>   long periods of time. Hence, it is best to transfer your Bitcoins to a
>   secure wallet.

What's the reason for that? It seems very weird to me. If I buy stock options, no one would object to me keeping them invested for years. Then why can't I leave my investment on a Bitcoin Exchange for a long period? Do I risk that the Exchange goes bankrupt or something like that?

---

Would this be an acceptable question for this site? If not, why?

Comment: Are you aware that there is a separate site devoted to questions about Bitcoin? https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @BenMiller yes I know, but [investement advice](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is off-topic on that site. That's why I never post there: I don't have questions about _the technology behind_ Bitcoins. I have a pretty good understanding of what a distributed ledger is - probably better than that of the average investor in Bitcoin. I _definitely_ (not probably) have a worse understanding of trading and investing in general, than that of the average investor in Bitcoin :-)

Comment: anyway, at this point you people have pretty much scared me out of investing even a tiny bit in Bitcoins, so I won't be asking my next question :-)

Comment: @DeltaIV I think a question about wallets vs. exchanges would be fine at bitcoin.stackexchange.com as that does relate to technology supporting Bitcoin. But you can check at https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/ as you have here whether it would be acceptable.

Comment: @ChrisWRea that makes sense. I would have liked to get an answer here (in-topic or off-topic?) before asking on another Meta site, but at this point I'll ask there too.,

Comment: Ps for the sake of completeness, I asked on the Bitcoin site and got a nice answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you surmised, your question ban was quite short and has now expired, so the simplest answer to the specific question in the title was just to wait a few days.

I think both your existing question and your proposed new question are on-topic for this site, as they both ask about Bitcoin in the context of personal finance.

I can't see anything obviously wrong with your existing question, it was reasonably well explained apart from the actual confusion that led to asking the question. So I don't know why it was downvoted so heavily (+3/-5 when I look now), and can't really be sure what the reaction to your proposed question would have been. In general Bitcoin questions seem to get an ok reception, [most of them are positively scored](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bitcoin?sort=votes&pageSize=50).

Deleting negatively scored posts doesn't usually help with bans.